# Catch only NS_ERROR_FILE_NO_DEVICE_SPACE

Tags: javascript, firefox

I catched a very unique exception on user's client side. And I need some mechanism how can I catch only this error? I can't use `instanceOf` operator because I don't know the instance of this error.